# Question from Mac Lane and Birkhoff (Chapter II Section 5) -- Universal property(?) of direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product, universal-property

This is problem 10 from section 5 of chapter II from "Algebra" by Mac Lane and Birkhoff. It says:

Let $E$ be the direct product of two cyclic groups $G$ and $H$ with generators $b$ and $c$ of 4orders $m$ and $n$, respectively. If a group $K$ has elements $u$ and $v$ with $u^m = 1$ and $v^n=1$, and $uv = vu$, prove that there exists a *unique* morphism $\phi:E\rightarrow K$ of groups with $\phi(b) = u$ and $\phi(c) = v$.

I feel like it's pretty easy to show that by defining the map $\phi$ by the rule $\phi(b^j, c^i) = u^jv^i$ gives a morphism of groups. And further, that $\phi(b,1) = u$ and $\phi(1,c) = v$. My problem is when it comes to showing that it is unique.

What I am thinking is to assume that we have another group morphism $\phi':E \rightarrow K$ which satisfies $\phi'(b,1) = u$ and $\phi'(1,c) = v$. Then, since this is a morphism it follows that $\phi'(b^i, c^j) = u^i v^j$. And so, for any $(b^l,c^k) \in E$ we have that $\phi(b^l,c^k)^{-1} \phi'(b^l, c^k) = c^{-k}b^{-l}b^lc^k = 1$. Which gives us that the two morphism agree, for every element in $E$.

Is this valid? Am I missing something? It just doesn't feel right for some reason, like I may be overlooking something(s).

Also, Mac Lane and Birkhoff call this a "universal property" but they don't really go into details about this (or at least I was not able to fully grasp the significance of this statement from the reading). Can anyone give a brief explanation of what exactly this means? If it's going to play a large role in what follows in their book, then feel free to just say to keep reading.

Comment: What definition of direct product are you using? I ask because, given presentations $G\cong\langle X_G\mid R_G\rangle$ and $H\cong\langle X_H\mid R_H\rangle$, one can define $G\times H$ as the group given by the presentation $$\langle X_G\sqcup X_H\mid  R_G\sqcup R_H\sqcup\{xy=yx : x\in X_G, y\in X_H\}\rangle.$$

Comment: I'm using their definition: $G \times H$ is all pairs $(g,h)$ with $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, with $(g,h)(g',h') = (gg', hh')$.

Comment: Your argument is correct: I suspect you are suspicious because it seemed too easy. I wouldn't worry too much about the formal definition of "universal property" (you can google for the formal definition, but it's not very meaningful until you've seen lots of examples, IMHO). Roughly speaking, it's a property of a construction that results in a canonical structure-preserving mapping from the constructed object to any object that shares some features with the constructed object. For now, I recommend you just read on.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks!